# Set tolerance for intersection in Geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to set tolerance 10^-8 for the intersection.

```
inte_s=gpd.overlay(shp,shpa,how='intersection')
```

How can you do that?

Comment: Can you be more precise on the desired outcome. Would using a buffer on one of the two dataframes be sufficient?